# PDO delete from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, sql-delete

I have a problem with a PDO code. 
I try the code below.

```
$id = null;

if ( !empty($_GET['t_id'])) {
    $id = $_REQUEST['t_id'];
}

$action = isset($_POST['_DELETE_']) ? $_POST['_DELETE_'] : "";

if ($action == 'do_not_delete') {
   header("Location: index.php?action=DEL_ERROR");
 }

if($action=='delete')  {

$host = "localhost";
$db_name = "_notice";
$username = "root";
$password = "111";

$con = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$db_name}", $username, $password);
$id = $_REQUEST['t_id'];
$query = "DELETE FROM topics WHERE topic_id = ?";
$stmt = $con->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(1, $id);
$exc = $stmt->execute();

if($exc){
$con = null;  
header("Location: index.php?action=DEL_OK");
}else{
$con = null;
header("Location: index.php?action=DEL_ERROR");
}}
```

Anything happens (dose not delete element from the database).
I have no errors on page; even when i use a try catch block, or page parameter like `index.php?action=DELETE`

Comment: `$_REQUEST['t_id']` doesn't match your `?action=DELETE`. Show us full code and what you tried exactly. In the meantime, add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: See Falc's answer about you not executing (least, not in posted code); if you are indeed "not" using that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call [$stmt->execute()](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.execute.php) after preparing the query and binding parameters.

**Update:**

You are checking the content of `$_GET['t_id']` but always setting $id to `$_REQUEST['t_id']`, and everything will execute only if `$_POST['_DELETE_']` contains `delete`.

Also, try to check the resulting query and parameters with [$stmt->debugDumpParams()](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.debugdumpparams.php) before executing and maybe replace your bindParam with `$stmt->bindParam(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT)`.